# Add First() Class Entity to <List> of Class Entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, nullreferenceexception

I'm working with an ASP.NET Forms application where (for simplicity) I added Model properties`[TotalService]` & `[PurchasedorReinstatedService]`where I am storing the value from another Model into this property for use in the first Model.

I am then trying to reference this Model property and set an ASP Label `.Text` property to it. Problem is, I keep getting NullReferenceExceptions, specifically:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PROJECT.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This is my custom control where I'm getting the error:

```
using PROJECT.Models.Default;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using PROJECT.Classes;

namespace PROJECT.CustomControls.Default
{
    public partial class YearsOfService : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public List<Years_Of_Service> yos { get; set; }
        public Years_Of_Service_Data yosd { get; set; }


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ApplyData();
            }
        }

        private void ApplyData()
        {
            salaryGridView.DataSource = yos;
            salaryGridView.DataBind();

            if (yosd.YearsOfService.OrderByDescending(y => y.TotalService).FirstOrDefault().ToString() != null)
            {
                creditSalLabel.Text = yosd.YearsOfService.OrderByDescending(y => y.TotalService).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                creditSalLabel.Text = String.Empty;
            }

            //creditSalLabel.Text = yosd.YearsOfService.OrderByDescending(y => y.TotalService).FirstOrDefault() != null ? yosd.YearsOfService.OrderByDescending(y => y.TotalService).FirstOrDefault().ToString() : String.Empty;

            //purchaseCreditLabel.Text = yosd.YearsOfService.OrderByDescending(y => y.PurchasedorReinstatedService).FirstOrDefault() != null ? yosd.YearsOfService.OrderByDescending(y => y.PurchasedorReinstatedService).FirstOrDefault().ToString() : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `Years_Of_Service` model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PROJECT.Models.Default
{
    public class Years_Of_Service
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string FiscalYear
        {
            get
            {
                return Year + "-" + (Year + 1);
            }
        }
        public decimal ServiceCredited { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public string CoveredEmployer { get; set; }

        // New properties added for Label Values
        public string TotalService { get; set; }
        public string PurchasedorReinstatedService { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Years_Of_Service_Data` Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PROJECT.Models.Default
{
    public class Years_Of_Service_Data
    {
        public List<Years_Of_Service> YearsOfService { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is the bit of code in my Helper where I am reading from my database results (`Oracle Data Reader`) into my Model entity (I have confirmed the values are getting correctly added to the `TotalService` & `PurchasedorReinstatedService` properties):

```
            while (odr.Read())
            {
                Years_Of_Service yosRecord = new Years_Of_Service();

                yosRecord.Year = gh.GetSafeInt(odr, 0);
                yosRecord.ServiceCredited = gh.ConvertNullDecimal(odr.GetValue(1));
                yosRecord.Salary = gh.ConvertNullDecimal(odr.GetValue(2));
                yosRecord.CoveredEmployer = gh.GetSafeString(odr, 3);

                // Use the Default Info Model Class - At_A_Glance Model properties to fill these properties for text labels.
                yosRecord.TotalService = defInfoOasis.At_A_Glance.CreditTotal.ToString("N5");
                yosRecord.PurchasedorReinstatedService = defInfoOasis.At_A_Glance.TotalPurchase.ToString("N5");
                yos.Add(yosRecord);
            }
```

What I need now is to add ANY of the `YearsOfService.yos` entities to the list of `List<Years_Of_Service> yosd` list. Anyone have any thoughts on how to go about this?

Below is how I'm setting the models listed under get/set in my CustomControls:

```
    private void GetDefaultInfoOasis()
    {
        DefaultInformation dio = new DefaultInformation);
        DefaultHelper dh = new DefaultHelper(Convert.ToInt32(Session["memberAccountId"]));

        dio = dh.GetDefaultInformation();

        // sets the Model Properties on the Custom Controls to that returned by [dio]
        AtAGlance.aag = dio.At_A_Glance;
        AnnualSalary.a_s = dio.Annual_Salary;
        YearsOfService.yos = dio.Years_Of_Service;

        // Attempting to add all or even 1 of the [dio.Years_Of_Service] or [YearsOfService.yos] (same thing) to the [YearsOfService.yosd] list:

        // Attempt 2: NULL Reference Exception
        YearsOfService.yosd.YearsOfService.Add(YearsOfService.yos.First());

        // Attempt 1: NULL Reference Exception
        YearsOfService.yosd.YearsOfService.Add(new Years_Of_Service { Salary = dio.Years_Of_Service.First().Salary, Year = dio.Years_Of_Service.First().Year, ServiceCredited = dio.Years_Of_Service.First().ServiceCredited, CoveredEmployer = dio.Years_Of_Service.First().CoveredEmployer, TotalService = dio.Years_Of_Service.First().TotalService, PurchasedorReinstatedService = dio.Years_Of_Service.First().PurchasedorReinstatedService });

        BeneficiaryDesignation.lb = dio.Beneficiaries;
    }
```

Anyone have an idea as to what I'm missing/doing wrong? This is probably the long roundabout way of getting what I want (currently adding the same value for [TotalService] and [PurchasedorReinstatedService] to all of my [Years_Of_Service] records) but it was the simplest I could come up with (without using global variables in my Helper...)

Comment: @DatRid his question is code specific

Comment: `YearsOfService.yosd.YearsOfService.Add(YearsOfService.yos.First());` 

yosd isn't static this won't work. You have to initialize YearsOfservice then do this.  yos also isn't static

Comment: by doing `YearsOfService.ysod` are you attempting to reference that user control on the current page? proper way would be to give that element an id then reference it with that

Comment: When I reference `YearsOfService.ysod`, I am setting a global value specified on my control: `protected global::MemberWeb2._0.CustomControls.Default.YearsOfService YearsOfService;`. It's a strange situation I keep tripping myself over, using the model entity `List<Years_Of_Service>` to list most of my data values in a rendered Grid, but needing 2 specific values simply for the specified `Label.Text`. Can you give me an example to help understand your second Comment? This is the closest solution I've gotten to, but I'm beginning to think I should seek out another way of getting my end result.

Comment: Second comment something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618656/need-to-reference-usercontrolascx-in-aspx-page-in-more-than-one-place-with-dif Passing it around to other places other than that page in asp.net you use `Session["usercontrolRef"] = AboutUsControl1` then you retrieve it somewhere else by doing `AboutUsControl AboutUsControl2 = (AboutUsControl) Session["usercontrolRef"]`. There are multiple ways to pass it around.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fight the `List<Years_Of_Service>.First()` insertion into `Years_Of_Service_Data`, I instead created a regular `Year_Of_Service` entity for my Custom Control to have access to:

```
namespace PROJECT.CustomControls.Default
{
    public partial class YearsOfService : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public List<Years_Of_Service> lyos { get; set; }
        public Years_Of_Service y_o_s { get; set; }


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ApplyData();
            }
        }

        private void ApplyData()
        {
            salaryGridView.DataSource = lyos;
            salaryGridView.DataBind();

            if (y_o_s.TotalService.ToString() != null)
            {
                creditSalLabel.Text = y_o_s.TotalService.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                creditSalLabel.Text = String.Empty;
            }

            if (y_o_s.PurchasedorReinstatedService.ToString() != null)
            {
                purchaseCreditLabel.Text = y_o_s.PurchasedorReinstatedService.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                purchaseCreditLabel.Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Default Page which uses my Custom Control:

```
    private void GetDefaultInformation()
    {
        DefaultInformation dio = new DefaultInformation();

        DefaultHelper dh = new DefaultHelper(Convert.ToInt32(Session["memberAccountId"]));

        dio = dh.GetDefaultInformation();

        AtAGlance.aag = dio.At_A_Glance;
        AnnualSalary.a_s = dio.Annual_Salary;
        YearsOfService.lyos = dio.Years_Of_Service;
        YearsOfService.y_o_s = dio.Years_Of_Service.First();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are initializing `YearsOfService.yosd` If that property is not set to a new object before doing this `YearsOfService.yosd.YearsOfService.Add(...)` then it will fail miserably.

Comment: When I reference `YearsOfService.ysod`, I am setting a global value specified on my custom control designer file (not really sure on this design, just following a coworkers lead): `protected global::PROJECT.CustomControls.Default.YearsOfService YearsOfService;`.